# Can I store the android's release.keystore file inside assets folder?

Tags: android, android-keystore, android-security

In the android developer page (http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#secure-key), it states:

> Keep the keystore file containing your private key in a safe, secure
> place.

Does it mean that we should keep the release.keystore file somewhere on our local computer (not inside the app)?

Or can I keep it inside the `src/main/assets` folder since the keystore is password protected? But on the other hand, the `keyPassword` and the `storePassword` is stored  inside the build.gradle file hence storing the release.keystore file inside `src/main/assets` is not a good idea? What is the most secured method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should keep `release.keystore` some place secure outside the application, like your local computer.

In case you want to update your application in future, you will only be able to update your application if you sign with the same key.

For example If you put it in your application and someone takes over it then they will be able to publish your application by signing with the key.

Edit: Official Android recommendation about securing key

> Your reputation as a developer entity depends on your securing your
>   private key properly, at all times, until the key is expired. Here are
>   some tips for keeping your key secure:
>
> - Select strong passwords for the keystore and key.
> - Do not give or lend    anyone your private key, and do not let    unauthorized persons know    your keystore and key passwords.
> - Keep    the keystore file containing    your private key in a safe,    secure    place.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Can you also point me to a link or an official document that can support your answer (because I cannot find it anywhere)? Or is this just common sense?

Comment: It's a common knowledge that you don't share your private keys with other and keep them secure.

Comment: If you want to read more from official Android page: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#secure-key

Comment: Do you mean that storing the keystore file inside the assets folder is not secured?

Comment: Of course it's not secure. Anyone with little knowledge can look into complied APK file and extract your key or any file you put in your application.

Answer (score 2):

## NO, never share your keystore in any way or form.

You keystore does not need, nor should it be inside your apps assets.

It is just for you to sign your release builds. Noone else should have it or know the password to it.

You need your keystore to prove that an app is really made by you. Which is also the reason why you have to sign your apps with the same keystore to be able to publish updates. Only you should be able to publish an update and you prove it by signing the app with your keystore.

If you hand out your keystore you are just enabling someone to guess or brute force your keystore password and then signing apps with it. In other words he can **pretend that he is you**.

You won't find any extensive documentation on this because this should just be common sense. It is the same technology that enables you to securly pay for something on the internet or send a signed email: public key cryptography.

---

In fact I am just baffled that you want to share your keystore, I can just assume you don't know what it is or what it does. That's why I tried to explain at least the bare basics above.

And as a side note since I feel compelled to mention that anyone can download your app from the appstore and look at your source code, resources  or assets - basically no technical knowledge required.
If you put your keystore into your assets and as such ship it along with your apk that would just be an early christmas for anyone  with a malicious intent. It's almost like handling the keys to your house to the burglars who want to rob you.

Comment: I know what a keystore does. I just didn't know that putting it in an assets folder is not safe. I didn't know that people can look at my assets after they have downloaded my app from playstore (Do they do it using a decomplier like this : [http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk](http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk) ?). Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @Sevin You only need a decompiler to look at the source code and some part of the resources. An apk is actually just a zip file and you can extract it the same way. Just change the extension of your apk to zip, extract it and see for yourself. If you want to look at the source code as well you need a special decompilers for Android. A popular one would for example be [**Apk Studio**](http://www.vaibhavpandey.com/apkstudio/).

Comment: @Sevin And nothing in your apk is safe. As soon as you release your app it is basically open source, and there is nothing you can do to prevent that. Keep that in mind when you develop an app.

Answer (score 0):

Best to make copies of it and store it on local computer/your online repository/google drive. If you lose it you won't be able to publish an update to the same application.